# how to display the address fields in the registration form

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-address, custom-field, registration

I was looking but I can not find a solution that will work.

---

**During registration on Magento 2.1.11, I would like to display the following additional fields:**

- address (required)
- mobile phone (required)
- company name (required)
- company's registration number (required)

---

It is a B2B wholesale site, so I only sell for companies. I would like all these fields to be required during registration.

maybe any have a solution?

Comment: have you created customer address attributes for mobile phone (required), company name (required)
& company's registration number (required)?

Comment: when I login to my account (as a customer) then I see these fields. Only the field with the company's registration number is missing. during registration visible only fields: first name, last name, e-mail & password

Comment: are you add company's registration number  right? all others fields already display right now.

Comment: unfortunately I do not know where I can add an extra field "company's registration number".

Comment: But my question others fields already display? For eg. Company, Tell Phone , Fax

Comment: Abdul,  Yes, other fields are visible only when I log in to the user's account, then I can complete these fields.

Comment: But address fields are need display on customer registration form right?

Comment: Add ans pls check and let me know any queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `customer_account_create.xml` file your current active theme

For eg.

> app/design/frontend/{YOUR_PACKAGE}/{YOUR_THEME}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

After add below code for display address field in registration form

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**After run below commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul, good job all works! I gave you a vote.  I'm missing now only the field for the "company's registration number". Do you know in which file can I add it?  I would also like to change the field "name of the company" to be required, will it do it in the database?  currently this field is not marked as required.

Comment: have you created customer address attribute for this?

Comment: How to get multiple addresses. like one of shipping one for billing?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that all the attributes you want to show in the registration form are already introduced in Magento.

To show the address fields:

> - create the file **`customer_account_create.xml`** under
>     app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/layout
>     folder.
> - Now paste below code in this file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields">
            <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

The main thing here is that you need to set **`true`** for setShowAddressFields argument.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the most correct! I created customer_account_create.xml with script and added it to the folder: app/design/frontend/MGS/Ethan/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml. I have refreshed XAMPP but unfortunately these fields are still not visible. Maybe I need to update with the magento command?

Answer (score 1):

Exact code is as follow in app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to display the address fields in the registration form **Magento 2.2.5** & **2.2.4**

1. Go to `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml`

and add a code    :  Line no :  **20**  Under

true
                   [image]

2. change the setting from Magento 2 admin